# C - Program not detecting blank spaces

Tags: c

I want my program to read a file containing words separated by blank spaces and then prints words one by one. This is what I did:

```
char *phrase = (char *)malloc(LONGMAX * sizeof(char));
char *mot = (char *)malloc(TAILLE * sizeof(char));
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("mots.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("err ");
} else {
    fgets(phrase, LONGMAX, fp);
    while (phrase[i] != '\0') {
        if (phrase[i] != " ") {
            mot[m] = phrase[i];
            i++;
            m++;
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", phrase[i]);
            mot = "";
        }
    }
}
```

but it isn't printing anything! Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You've never initialized `i` as far as I can see.

Comment: You're not showing the declaration of either `i` nor `m`. But, I suspect they're _unitialized_ (i.e. they have random values). Do (e.g.): `int i = 0; int m = 0;` to set them initially. Because you have created `mot` from `malloc`, you can _not_ do `mot=""`. This is a memory leak. You want: `mot[0] = 0;` instead. And, probably, you want to reset `m` at the same time?

Comment: Hint: `" "` is a *string*, `' '` is a *character*.

Comment: M and i are both initialised at 0

Comment: This requires you to extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `i` in the following:

```
while (phrase[i]!='\0'){
```

Should be initialized to `0` before being used, then incremented as you iterate through the string.

You have not shown where/how it is created.

Also in this line,

```
if(phrase[i]!=" "){
```

the code is comparing a *char*: (`phrase[i]`) with a *string*: ( `" "` )

```
//  char        string
if(phrase[i] !=  " "  ){
```

change it to:

```
//  char        char  
if(phrase[i] != ' '){  
//or better yet, include all whitespace:
if(isspace(phrase[i]) {
```

There is no error checking in the following, but it is basically your code with modifications.  Read comments for explanation on edits to `fgets()` usage, casting return of `malloc()`, how and when to terminate the output buffer `mot`, etc.:

This performs the following:  *read a file containing words separated by blank spaces and then prints words one by one.*

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int m = 0;
    char* phrase=malloc(LONGMAX);//sizeof(char) always == 0
    if(phrase)//test to make sure memory created
    {
        char* mot=malloc(TAILLE);//no need to cast the return of malloc in C
        if(mot)//test to make sure memory created
        {
            FILE* fp=NULL;
            fp=fopen("_in.txt","r");
            if(fp)//test to make sure fopen worked
            {//shortcut of what you had :) (left off the print err)
                i = 0;
                m = 0;
                while (fgets(phrase,LONGMAX,fp))//fgets return NULL when no more to read.
                {
                    while(phrase[i] != NULL)//test for end of last line read
                    {
                       // if(phrase[i] == ' ')//see a space, terminate word and write to stdout
                        if(isspace(phrase[i])//see ANY white space, terminate and write to stdout

                        {

                            mot[m]=0;//null terminate
                            if(strlen(mot) > 0) printf("%s\n",mot);
                            i++;//move to next char in phrase.
                            m=0;//reset to capture next word 
                        }
                        else
                        {

                             mot[m] = phrase[i];//copy next char into mot
                             m++;//increment both buffers
                             i++;//       "           
                        }
                    }

                    mot[m]=0;//null terminate after while loop
                }
                //per comment about last word.  Print it out here.
                mot[m]=0;
                printf("%s\n",mot);
                fclose(fp);
            }
            free(mot);
        }
        free(phrase);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you! This works but doesn't print the last word

Comment: Done! Thank you so much :) 

I have been coding in java/python/scala for 6 years. i have to admit C is way harder

Answer (score 3):

```
phrase[i]!=" "
```

You compare character (`phrase[i]`) and string (`" "`). If you want to compare `phrase[i]` with space character, use `' '` instead.

If you want to compare string, use `strcmp`.

```
printf("%s\n",phrase[i]);
```

Here, you use `%s` for printing the string, but `phrase[i]` is a character.

Do not use `mot="";` to copy string in c. You should use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(mot, " ");
```

If you want to print word by word from one line of string. You can use `strtok` to split string by space character.

```
fgets(phrase,LONGMAX,fp);
char * token = strtok(phrase, " ");
while(token != NULL) {
   printf("%s \n", token);
   token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

OT, your program will get only one line in the file because you call only one time `fgets`. If your file content of many line, you should use a loop for `fgets` function.

```
while(fgets(phrase,LONGMAX,fp)) {
   // do something with pharse string. 
   // strtok for example.
   char * token = strtok(phrase, " ");
   while(token != NULL) {
      printf("%s \n", token);
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program has multiple problems:

- the test for end of file is incorrect: you should just compare the return value of `fgets()` with `NULL`.
- the test for spaces is incorrect: `phrase[i] != " "` is a type mismatch as you are comparing a character with a pointer. You should use `isspace()` from `<ctype.h>`

Here is a much simpler alternative that reads one byte at a time, without a line buffer nor a word buffer:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int inword = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            if (inword) {
                putchar('\n');
                inword = 0;
            }
        } else {
            putchar(c);
            inword = 1;
        }
    }
    if (inword) {
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```